# If a line and curve touch each other, prove that slope of the curve at the point is equal to the line

Tags: geometry

Let's say there is a straight line and a curve. At  a point  'A' they just touch other.  Will the slope of the curve at point 'A' be same as that of line?

Comment: What is your definition of the slope of a curve at a point? Because to me it is, _by definition_, the slope of the touching line.

Comment: To me, on the other hand, the definition of touching is *having the same slope at the point of intersection*.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Fair enough. That's a different way to have basically the same issue: What makes this not trivial from the definitions of either "touching" or "slope"?

Comment: @Arthur I agree in full.

Comment: Statement is not true!!! You have give more precide statement. For example, the curve for $y^2=x^3$ has $Y$-axis as a **touching** line...

Comment: @SaucyO'Path / Arthur, IMO, **touching** line can be defined as a line which meets the curve (set theoretic intersection) in only one point in an arbitrariliy small neighbourhood.

Comment: @user5325 The line $y = 0$ only intersects $y = x^2 - x$ once in a very small neighbourhood about the origin, but I wouldn't call that touching. On the other hand, $y = 0$ does definitely touch $y = x^4 - x^3$ at the origin. I see no set theoretical difference between the two, whatsoever.

Comment: @user5325 So for instance, given a line $r$, a line $s$ is a touching line to $r$ if and only if $s$ is no parallel to $r$. (Corollary: $r$ doesn't touch $r$).

Comment: @SaucyO'Path / Arthur, thanks for clearing my concept!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition " the slope of a curve y = f(x) at the point P means the slope of the tangent at the point P. " Tangent is basically the line which just touch the curve at a point. Thus OP 's statement is true by definition.
https://www.intmath.com/differentiation/2-slope-tangent.php